# Kernel error in Jupyter notebook, how to fix?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Having an issue connecting to kernel in Jupyter. I receive these errors

Restoring connection for dac234cb-50d8-407d-b73c-5932620239ba:ef9a42d833f44466945d3f0a0032ffa9
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-453' coro=<WebSocketProtocol13.write_message..wrapper() done, defined at /home/tangramer/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py:1090> exception=WebSocketClosedError()>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tangramer/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 1092, in wrapper
    await fut
tornado.iostream.StreamClosedError: Stream is closed
 
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/tasks.py", line 232, in __step
    result = coro.send(None)
  File "/home/tangramer/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 1094, in wrapper
    raise WebSocketClosedError()
tornado.websocket.WebSocketClosedError
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-463' coro=<WebSocketProtocol13.write_message..wrapper() done, defined at /home/tangramer/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py:1090> exception=WebSocketClosedError()>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tangramer/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 1092, in wrapper
    await fut
tornado.iostream.StreamClosedError: Stream is closed
 
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/tasks.py", line 232, in __step
    result = coro.send(None)
  File "/home/tangramer/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 1094, in wrapper
    raise WebSocketClosedError()
tornado.websocket.WebSocketClosedError

I am stuck and not sure what to try next

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.